# ¿Como puedo hacer para que me salgan los estilos CSS y de Bootstrap en el navegador de chrome?

Tags: python, html5, django

¡Hola! Tengo un problema con una aplicación web que estoy desarrollando con el framework Django. Los estilos de las páginas no se cargan y al revisar las herramientas de desarrollador, aparece un error 404. El error indica que no se encuentra la ruta de los estilos CSS y Bootstrap.

Este error comenzó a aparecer hace poco. Antes, los estilos se cargaban sin ningún problema. Probé en otro navegador y el error persiste. He adjuntado una imagen con el error para que puedan verlo mejor.

¿Podrían ayudarme a solucionar este problema? No sé qué más puedo hacer.

Aquí hay algunos detalles adicionales que pueden ser relevantes:

[image: Error al cargar estilos]

Comment: Tal vez cambiaste la ruta de los archivos CSS y no los modificaste en el código. Revisa eso o agrega un screenshot con la estructura de tu proyecto y el bloque de código con el que importas los archivos y tal vez alguien te puede orientar.

Comment: Yo lo que haría es mirar el settings.py que STATIC_URL = '/static/' entonces ya podrás referenciar en tu HTML el Css con: `<link href="/static/my_app/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` Si tienes más dudas comparte tu código y te ayudo

Comment: Puedes agregar a la pregunta como estas cargando los estilos en tu aplicación